# How to exclude Super Table rows matching given entry

Tags: plugin-supertable

I can't quite figure out how to make this work:

Say I have two sections, Actors and Movies.

In my Actor section, I've got a Super Table field (myFilmography) with an Entries column to choose a single entry from the Movies section.

On a given actor's page, I'd like to output the contents of the Super Table, excluding rows containing a match for a given movie(s).

I've tried filtering on the id of the movie's entry, like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
{% set myMoviesExceptJaws = entry.myFilmography.movies('id NOT 874').all() %}
```

How do I filter out rows containing specific entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get this `id NOT 874` syntax? I don't think that's supported. Entry fields already allow you to serach for related entries by ID, so one of those should work:

```
{% set myMoviesExceptJaws = entry.myFilmography.movies(['not', 574]).all() %}

{% set myMoviesExceptJaws = entry.myFilmography.movies('not 574').all() %}
```